# Stitch two images using openCV in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, image, opencv

I want stitch the several images in iOS.
So i used the openCV framework.
Here is my code. But i got error..

/Volumes/WORK/Panogram/Panogram/Frameworks/OpenCV.framework/Headers/opencv2/stitching/warpers.hpp:46:10: 'detail/warpers.hpp' file not found

I want anyone help me how to use openCV in iOS for image stitching..
And i think my framework has problem.. if anyone did similar work with me, then help me please.

```
#import <OpenCV/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import "UIImage+OpenCV.h"
#import <OpenCV/opencv2/stitching/stitcher.hpp>

@interface TakePhotoViewController ()

@end

@implementation TakePhotoViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    UIImage* testImg1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"002.jpg"];
    UIImage* testImg2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"003.jpg"];

    cv::vector<cv::Mat> images;

    images.push_back([testImg1 CVMat]);
    images.push_back([testImg2 CVMat]);

    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(YES);

    Stitcher::Status st1 = stitcher.stitch(images, imgResult);
    /////////add image to uiimageview
    UIImage *image=  [self UIImageFromCVMat:imgResult];
    imgView.image=image;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem in the past. I simply created a folder named 'detail' in the directory and copied warpers.hpp to the folder. Your system probably doesn't have 'detail'folder in the directory or has warpers.hpp in the same directory as detail folder when it needs to be in the folder.

Comment: But I think my opencv framework is not correct. If you did similar job with me, please give me correct opencv framework and sample code that working well for you.

Comment: hey i need some helop, can you give solution?